# Facebook IOS sdk: FBSDKLoginBehavior on native not supported

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm looking for a sign in with facebook integration for my ios app.
But I read this in the changelog of the SDK (version 6.0.0)

```
LOGINKIT
FBSDKLoginBehavior Login flows no longer support logging in through the native application. This change reflects that.
```

So if I understand it correct, you can't sign in anymore with facebook on you IOS app or are there other possiblities?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you find this? I can't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct, updating the sdk on an app that’s using an older version will trigger build errors anywhere ‘.native’ is specified. The only fb login behavior option available now is ‘.browser’